# Какую JavaScript библиотеку можно использовать для разработки сайта на Struts 2?

Tags: javascript, java, веб-программирование, поиск-библиотек, struts

Какую JavaScript библиотеку *можно* использовать для разработки web-сайта на Struts 2?

Answer (score 1):

[Angular](http://angular.ru/) отлично ложиться на Struts2 REST плагин например

В принципе с любым фреймворком общего назначения не должно быть проблем

Comment: Struts2 REST работает не только с Angular, но и с обычными темплейтами типа JSP, а также позволяет иметь гибридную конфигурацию REST и Convention.

Comment: Немного ошибаетесь, т.к. Struts 2 изначально использовал dojo фреймворк для своих темплейтов, но как только dojo стал расти, плагин с dojo стал деприкатед. На его смену пришел jquery, но так и не стал официальным. В настоящее время используется чистый JavaScript. Поэтому, говорить, что нет проблем с фреймворками нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете JSP, или Freemarker, или Velocity то возможно вам подойдет JQuery. Ктому же есть плагин [struts2-jquery](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery), который позволяет генерить javascript код на jsp страницах.

> Плагин для популярной Java веб-платформы struts2 для обеспечения функциональных возможностей Ajax и UI виджетов, основанный на яваскрипте фрейворка JQuery.

Хотя, если смотреть на Struts2 как бэкенд, то это неплохая альтернатива Spring MVC, и действительно, используя [struts2-json-plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/) или [struts2-rest-plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/rest/), то можно передавать данные туда и обратно в формате JSON. В этом случае любая библиотека, используемая на фронте типа Angular или React.js подойдёт, так как используется в основном REST и JSON.